# How to remove width with center DIV

Tags: html, css

HTML `<div align="center">` is out of date and I switch to use CSS

```css
.center 
{
  margin:0 auto;
  width : 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  This is some text!
</div>
```

I was having problems with width attribute. I want this div auto fit with content in this div but with `width : 70%;` it not fit but when I remove width attribute so this div not center of page.

I want this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/puYi0.jpg

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take the `width` as per the content you can use `display:inline-block` and set css to parent as `text-align:center` which will align the `element` `center`

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
.center {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="center">
    This is some text!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `inline-block` takes the `width` of the children and `block` takes full `width` so by adding `width` you can change the `width` to `xx%` and align it by `margin:0 auto` but in `inline-block` you can align it by simply adding `text-align:center` to parent

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `width` property and add `text-align:center` to `.center` element

```css
.center 
{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  This is some text!
</div>
```

Comment: there is no need for `margin:0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="center">This is in the center of the screen</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.center 
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width : 70%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center" style="border: 1px solid red;">
  This is some text!
</div>
```

I added a red border for you to confirm the result.
1. Width = 70%
2. Text inside is aligned center

Comment: No, this div not fit content inside this div. You can see what I want here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/puYi0.jpg